# Get the String values of Tags in an Array using Shell Script

Tags: xml, shell

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subject>
  <name>Operating System</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory + Lab</type>
  <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject>
  <name>Web Development</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Only Lab</type>
 </subject>

</classes>
```

Expected Output:

```
index 0 : Operating System
index 1 : 3
index 2 : Theory + Lab
index 3 : Prof. XYZ
index 4 : Web Development
index 5 : 3
index 6 : Only Lab
```

I tried using `sed` command, but the command is not storing the result in a format that I want.

Command:

`declare -a totalArray=($(sed -n '/\s*<subject>/,/<\/subject>/p' file.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e '/^\s*$/d' -e 's/\s*//g'))`

And when I'm printing the array elements, I'm getting results as:

```
index 0 : OperatingSystem
index 1 : 3
index 2 : Theory+Lab
index 3 : Prof.XYZ
index 4 : WebDevelopment
index 5 : 3
index 6 : OnlyLab
```

I need suggestions on how to add the spaces between two words.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is not the optimal program for this kind of task. You better use  the program [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet). It was specifically designed for that kind of task. So use this command (which is a one-line version of an XSLT stylesheet):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/classes/subject/*" -v "concat('index ',position()-1,' : ',.)" -n input.xml
```

Its output is:

```
index 0 : Operating System
index 1 : 3
index 2 : Theory + Lab
index 3 : Prof. XYZ
index 4 : Web Development
index 5 : 3
index 6 : Only Lab
```

Here, the options are

- `sel`: chooses the 'selection'  mode
- `-t`: template mode
- `-m`: matches an XPath expression
- `-v`: retrieves the value relative to the context node (here set by the `-m` option)
- `-n`: outputs a newline after each match